# Python xml.etree.ElementTree Parsing multiple .xml files

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to parse multiple xml files using Python ElementTree.
Part of my code is as follows:

```
dirSelected = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()

# User names the output csv file
csvFile = raw_input('Enter the name for the result csv file ')
csvFile = csvFile + ".csv"
resultCSV = open(csvFile, "w+")

# Formation of a long string that becomes the header of the csv file
resultCSV_header = 'header,' + 'header2,'
print (resultCSV_header, file = resultCSV)  

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirSelected):
    for fi in files:
        #parse S1.xml files       
        if (fi.endswith('.xml') and fi.startswith('S')):
            filePath = os.path.join(root, fi)
            #Parse XML directly from the file path
            tree = ET.parse(filePath)
            #Get the root node
            doc = tree.getroot()
            column1 = doc.find('.//TAG1').text
            ...
            resultCSV_recipe = (column1 + "," + column2 + ...)
                print (resultCSV_xml)
                print (resultCSV_xml, file=resultCSV)
```

My problem is that I am trying to parse multiple *.xml files and putting the data into one row of the *.csv output file. For example, I have S1.xml, S2.xml, C1.xml, C2.xml in the selected folder, and I want the data from S1.xml and C1.xml to be put into one row of the output file. My output file is a simple *.csv file that I hope to open with Excel, with rows and columns defined by myself.

I can currently parse all the TAGs from S1.xml to the output and it works fine, but when I try to parse C1.xml by walking through all the files and dirs in the selected folder, I have some trouble in the for loop and the output parameters. Showing "local variable 'column1' referenced before assignment".

Is it possible to concatenate multiple *.xml files in one folder using Python. Or are there better functions for parsing *.xml files.
Thank you everyone for this!!!

Comment: If you just concatenate two XML documents, the result isn't a valid XML document, so that's not likely to be the way to solve your problem. (If you want to do it anyway, it's easy—see the `fileinput` module, or `itertools.chain`. But presumably you don't want to do something that isn't going to help solve your problem.)

Comment: Meanwhile, if you want us to help solve your problem, please show the actual error message and traceback, ideally with a stripped-down version of your code and sample data that reproduces it. Clearly the error is happening in some code you haven't shown above (which can't be your actual code, because the `print` statements are indented despite not being in an kind of suite).